# Does an error thrown by an 'after insert/update' trigger cause the insert/update to fail?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

If I have an `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE` trigger on a table, and the trigger fails (causes an error), will that cause the original `INSERT` or `UPDATE` to fail? I know the trigger happens after (hence the `AFTER` keyword), but does it abort the transaction (implicit or explicit), etc.?

Specifically regards SQL Server 2005, but I'm interested in info for 2000, 2005, and 2008. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found [an article](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#triggercontext) saying it does, at least in SQL Server 2000. Quoting:

> You have *trigger context* when you are in a trigger, or you are in a stored procedure, user-defined function or block of dynamic SQL that has been called directly or indirectly from a trigger. That is, somewhere on the call stack, there is a trigger. If you are in trigger context, all errors terminate the batch and roll back the transaction on the spot.

Comment: I believe they are in the same transaction, that is the reason why it will rollback the original insert/update. So this is indeed the reason.